# Origin of "chuck a wobbly"?

Tags: slang, dialects, australian-english

[**Chuck a wobbly**](http://andc.anu.edu.au/australian-words/meanings-origins?field_alphabet_value=281) is Australian slang for someone throwing a tantrum, and I like it because it invokes amusing imagery.

I'm not certain of its origins however. I can see how it may be equivalent to the similar-meaning idiom "throw a fit", where "chuck" is also Australian slang for "throw", but I can't be certain of what "wobbly" is supposed to mean. It's more difficult to nail down because as far as I know, "wobbly" isn't used in other phrases in Australian slang.

Comment: I can see flailing limbs possibly being described as "wobbly".

Comment: _Throw a wobbly_ is well-known in the UK, but I don't recall hearing _chuck a wobbly_ here.

Comment: In UK it's normally a wobbler rather than a wobbly. See http://idiom-a-day.blogspot.co.uk/2010/10/throw-wobbler.html?m=1

Comment: @k1eran It's never a "wobbler" [sic] in the UK, but always a wobbly!

Comment: @PeterPoint see http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/throw+a+wobbler

Comment: I was born in England soon after WW2, and emigrated to the USA in 1980. I never heard the expression in the thirty-odd years I lived in the UK, and just came across it today in The Times Cryptic Crossword book 18 (published in 2014). Surprisingly, one of the other clues related to an old American strip cartoon. I'm surprised that I had never heard the expression, as I worked with all types of people in the London area, including many whose language was peppered with slang.

Comment: Whereas I've been fairly familiar with 'throw a wobbler' for far longer than with 'throw a wobbly'.

Comment: @PeterPoint: It may be a regional thing - "throw a wobbler" is certainly what's used in the places I've lived (S England). I've never heard "wobbly", though I'd understand what someone meant if I heard it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Chucking a wobbly* comes from *throw a wobbly* and *wobbly* refers to a fit of anger, possibly suggesting the person is mentally unbalanced.

---

The 1994 *Shorter Slang Dictionary* (Partridge, Beale, Fergusson) says:

> **throw a wobbly** to become angry, agitated or mentally unbalanced; to behave irrationally or unpredictably. Later 20th century.

The 2008 *New Partridge Dictionary of Slang and Unconventional English* says:

> **wobbly** *noun* a fit of anger *UK, 1977*. < **throw a wobbly** to have a fit
>   of bad temper or anger *NEW ZEALAND, 1984*

The OED says:

> ***to throw a wobbly*** : to lose one's self-control in a fit of nerves, panic, temperament, annoyance, or the like; also, to act in an unexpected way, causing surprise or consternation.

Their first quotation is from the Brisbane *Telegraph* on 13 April 1977.

---

I found the phrase slightly earlier in the Australian Trove archive of newspapers in *[The Canberra Times](http://trove.nla.gov.au/ndp/del/article/110728147?searchTerm=%22throw%20a%20wobbly%22&searchLimits=sortby=dateAsc)* of 12 March 1977:

> The story begins with
>   Howard Beale, a
>   nationally-broadcast news
>   commentator, **throwing a
>   wobbly** on camera and
>   getting fired.

It shows up in a 1964 Google Books snippet of *[The Watersiders](http://books.google.com/books?id=_D1AAAAAIAAJ&q=%22throw%20a%20wobbly%22%20OR%20%22chuck%20a%20wobbly%22&dq=%22throw%20a%20wobbly%22%20OR%20%22chuck%20a%20wobbly%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=bHVIUte1EK7Y4QTOsoHYBw&ved=0CDQQ6AEwAQ)* by Michael Davis:

> They were laying down long planks at odd angles from the square as though about to participate in some peculiar rite. "What's the matter, mate? You look queer. Ain't going to **throw a wobbly**, are you?"

Google Books snippets are sometimes wrong, but the [author, title and year](http://www.worldcat.org/title/watersiders/oclc/317076212?referer=di&ht=edition) seem correct and it was published in Australia so it's plausible.

Another Google Books snippet is from the 1972 *[Parliamentary Debates](http://books.google.com/books?id=hl8hAQAAIAAJ&q=%22throw%20a%20wobbly%22%20OR%20%22chuck%20a%20wobbly%22&dq=%22throw%20a%20wobbly%22%20OR%20%22chuck%20a%20wobbly%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=bHVIUte1EK7Y4QTOsoHYBw&ved=0CD0Q6AEwAw)* of New Zealand:

> Mr Moyle — Perhaps he will throw a plum at them. Mr TIZARD — He can throw a plum, or he can **throw a "wobbly"**, which is more in keeping with the Minister. He complained that the Opposition did not congratulate the Government and the ...

Searching for 1972 brings up correct-looking results. Furthermore, [Colin Moyle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colin_Moyle) was an MP from 1963-1977 (and 1981-1990), as was [Bob Tizard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bob_Tizard) from (1957-1960 and) 1963-1990.

Comment: I've sent this antedating and possible antedatings to the OED.

Answer (score 3):

Definitively, throwing a wobbly refers to Constable Plod, of Enid Blyton fame, whose cartoon character's head would wobble around anytime he became agitated or was confronted with a challenging situation. This is exactly the same meaning as today. It started out as a quaint idiosyncratic behaviour of a rather endearing cartoon character, and has matured into a standard description of anyone who's lost control and displaying erratic begaviour. I grew up in England in the 1950s, and Constable Plod "throwing a wobbly" was a source of delight to me as a young child as I watched Noddy and the rest of his friends.

Comment: Interesting. How did it become Australian slang, then?

Comment: Australian usage almost certainly followed directly from English usage. So much of the English language has made its way into other languages, but Australian in particular is heavily derived from the mother tongue. I have always thought of Australia as being like Canada, but with sunshine, and both speaking the good ol' English language.

Comment: You could be right, but you haven't given any concrete evidence. Can you [edit] this to add some references or sources? For example, do the books ever use the word wobbly?

Answer (score 1):

CHUCK: Is the Aussie term for THROW WOBBLY: Is uncontrollable or or unstable shaking, as in a 'fit'.

Henceforth it follows that we Australians have 'converted' the English phrase to "throw a fit", into our own domestic terminology.

Comment: Hello, Graeme. Good / desirable answers on ELU will almost always be accompanied by supporting references, linked and attributed. Hence Hugo's answer has been heavily upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

There's an interesting discussion here: http://www.wordwizard.com/phpbb3/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=20663

I find the most interesting suggestion here:

WOBBLY ►adjective (wobblier, wobbliest) unsteady; shaky; inclined to wobble. ►noun (wobblies) colloquial a fit of anger; a tantrum. • wobbliness noun. • throw a wobbly colloquial to have a tantrum; to rage. 1970s as a noun.

Answer (score 0):

I always assumed "chuck a wobbly" was a reference to the propensity of the Industrial Workers of the World, aka Wobblies, to go on strike - which could be seen as a kind of tantrum-throwing, which is roughly what the modern phrase meant in the usage when I was growing up, long after the IWW had disappeared but not necessarily their cultural memory.

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest it is derived from 'throwing a fit' and is intended as indicative of the involuntary spasms of someone suffering an epileptic seizure (commonly called 'a fit')

Comment: You "would suggest" - do you have any backup for this, or is it just speculation?